# Undefined variable $totalPrice getting this error i want print $totalPrice in html code form jQuery. not working code after success status

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

> Undefined variable $totalPrice

getting this error i want print $totalPrice in html code form jQuery. not working code after success status

```
    
        function applyCouponCode() {
            jQuery('#coupon_code_msg').html('');
            var coupon_code = jQuery('#coupon_code').val();
            if (coupon_code != '') {

                jQuery.ajax({
                    // url: '{{ route('apply_coupon_code') }}',
                    // method: "POST",
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/apply_coupon_code',
                    data: 'coupon_code=' + coupon_code + '&_token=' + jQuery("[name='_token']").val(),
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result.status == 'success') {
                            jQuery('.show_coupon_box').removeClass('hide');
                            jQuery('#coupon_code_str').html(coupon_code);
                            jQuery('#total_price').html('INR ' + result.totalPrice);
                            jQuery('.apply_coupon_code_box').hide();
                        } else {

                        }
                        jQuery('#coupon_code_msg').html(result.msg);
                    }
                });
            } else {

                jQuery('#coupon_code_msg').html('Please enter coupon code');
            }
        }

        function remove_coupon_code() {
            jQuery('#coupon_code_msg').html('');
            var coupon_code = jQuery('#coupon_code').val();
            jQuery('#coupon_code').val('');
            if (coupon_code != '') {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/remove_coupon_code',
                    data: 'coupon_code=' + coupon_code + '&_token=' + jQuery("[name='_token']").val(),
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result.status == 'success') {
                            jQuery('.show_coupon_box').addClass('hide');
                            jQuery('#coupon_code_str').html('');
                            jQuery('#total_price').html('INR ' + result.totalPrice);
                            jQuery('.apply_coupon_code_box').show();
                        } else {

                        }
                        jQuery('#coupon_code_msg').html(result.msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

this is my html code

```
<ul>
                                            @php $total = 0 @endphp
                                            @foreach ($cart as $details)
                                                @php $total += $details->product_price * $details->quantity @endphp
                                            @endforeach
                                            <li>Cart Subtotal<span>{{ $total }}</span></li>
                                            <tr class="hide show_coupon_box">
                                                <th>Coupon Code <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="remove_coupon_code()"
                                                        class="remove_coupon_code_link">Remove</a></th>
                                                <td id="coupon_code_str"></td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <li>Shipping<span>Free</span></li>
                                            {{-- <li class="last" id="total_price">You 
                                         Pay<span>{{ $totalPrice }}</span>
                                            </li> --}}
                                            <td id="total_price">INR {{ $totalPrice }}</td>
                                        </ul>
```

Comment: fyi, `<tr>` and `<td>` are not allowed inside `<ul>`

Comment: So, where is `$totalPrice` set in your blade? `$total` is being set, but not `$totalPrice`. Is this a `jquery` or a `php` problem?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. You don't have `$totalPrice` set in your `php`. The `jQuery` has nothing to do with it, and you can edit it out of the question. You might be thinking that jQuery can pass data to PHP, which it can't, since PHP is the first to run whenever a page is called, and it only runs once when the page loads

Answer (score 1):

You bring in the TotalPrice value by using jQuery does not mean you can define the TotalPrice in the TD.

Change the code :

```
<td id="total_price">INR {{ $totalPrice }}</td>
```

To :

```
<td id="total_price"></td>
```

If no other errors, the totalPrice value will be brought in into the total_price id's TD and the value will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to jQuery, you don't have initialized `$totalPrice` in your blade file, either send it from your backend in compact or make in your blade file.

One more thing if you are assigning [`$totalPrice`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vhZl.png) to HTML like in the pic then you don't need to do `{{$totalPrice}}`